# What is this type of interface?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, connector, identification

what is this type of interface, located at the very edge of the PCB? What's interface standard, and what is pinout? The 5 holes in yellow circles is GND.

[image: Interface]

Comment: likely no standard and unknown pinout. We have not even an idea on what board that is or where it is connected to. Do you have an idea how many possibilities there are for 5 pins?

Comment: Looks to me like an impedance test strip (that would also explain the GND holes) to be honest although it could be anything else.

Comment: Those look like they're intended to be populated with connectors that an external logic analyzer could be plugged into. But without documentation that indicates what the connector part number might be, or at least what brand of analyzer to use, this could be very hard to track down.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That looks like half of a Mictor connector footprint for a logic analyzer.  Mictor connectors are relatively high speed connectors that usually have 38 surface mount signal pins in two rows of 19 and five through hole ground pins in the center line.  This footprint looks like that, but with the surface mount pads only on one side.  It's possible that the pads on the other side are routed off on this board, but could be left on for development models.

Comment: Yes, definitely Mictor connectors, possibly discontinued, since they are not listed in their product list.